# Sed regex to capture upto one word before the pattern string and after the string

Tags: sed

**Below is just template example. Wanted a generalised regex**

This template acts as a doorway by helping to develop a database "query", before running it on the wiki, and it does this by way of a search link that can also be used to share such discoveries. This template can also be used to have "learn",string    "regular",string    "expression",string syntax of this version of Cirrus Search.

**Regex 1:**

To capture groups upto pattern string.

Eg: Pattern=query

Using sed to **Capture group** upto "query" and after "query,,"

[Note: comma after query is optional may or may not be present hence capture group 1 should contain upto *query* and capture group 2 should contain *before.*"]

Tried:

```
sed 's/^(.*?)"query"(.*)/\1\2/g'
```

Above works. But capture group 2 contains comma that i dont want comma and comma is optional need to used like [,].
Help Needed for above.

**Regex 2:**

To capture groups upto a **word before the pattern**

Eg: Pattern:"regular"

So,
capture group one should contain **all text upto "learn"** and capture group 2 contain everythinh  including after **string    "expression"**

[Means: Not capturing **,string    "regular",**]

Tried:

```
sed 's/^(.*?)"\w"[^\"]*"regular"([^"]*)(.*)/\1\3/g' -rE
```

But not working. I have used "\w" for generalised regex thats what i want.

**Regex 3: Query regarding capture groups in sed**

Is there a way to search for captured group or edit the capture group itself

For eg: sed -r '/(someword)(.*)/ s/\1/something/g'
Is something like that or alternative possible

Comment: `Above works.` did you miss `-r` or `-E` or `--regexp-extended` argument?

Comment: Also regarding `Above works` - `.*?` is undefined behavior in a BRE or an ERE as it's a repetition char `*` (0-or-many ) followed immediately by another repetition char `?` (0-or-1) so YMMV.

Comment: Regarding `-rE` - `-r` activates EREs in old versions of GNU sed while `-E` activates EREs in new versions of GNU sed and in BSD sed. It doesn't make sense to use both. Regarding `I have used "\w" for generalised regex` - assuming you want `\w` to mean "word consituent character" that's not what it means in general, when used in general (i.e. without using GNU sed) it means the literal character `w`. If you in general (i.e. portably) want "word consistuent characters" as defined by the POSIX standard that'd be `[[:alnum:]_]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to search for captured group or edit the capture group itself

You can split pattern space into chunks, hold it to hold space, extract only interested part, do edit on it, then take hold space back and shuffle pattern space back to original line.

```
s/\(someword\)\(.*\)/\n\2\n\1/   # split pattern space into chunks
h                                # hold it to hold space
s/.*\n//                         # extract only interested part
s/.*/something/                  # do edit on it
G                                # take hold space back
s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\).*/\2\1\3/    # shuffle
```

Above I used newline character as chunks separator. Side note that using `\n` inside `replacement` part of `s` command is generally an extension over POSIX, but I think works everywhere.

> Wanted a generalised regex

Use a real programming language, *tokenize* input and work on tokens then output them. Python, Perl, AWK are waiting for you.

---

> Captured group has "word,word2" and i want to remove ,

The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '
  s/\(word,word\)\(.*\)/\n\2\n\1/
  h
  s/.*\n//
  s/,//
  G
  s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\).*/\2\1\3/
' <<<'stuff1, word,word ,stuff2'
```

outputs:

```
stuff1, wordword ,stuff2
```

Comment: Ok. But what if i want to edit the captured word. Eg. Captured group has "word,word2" and i want to remove ,

Comment: `You can split pattern space into chunks, hold it to hold space, extract only` the captured word, then edit the captured word with `s/,//`, `then take hold space back and shuffle pattern space back to original line`. You can learn sed at  https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html .

Comment: Thanks.Now i got it how sed works. Have to visualize the logic and then apply the syntax. But can you explain why sed 's/^(.*?)"\w"[^\"]*"regular"([^"]*)(.*)/\1\3/g' -rE isnt working

Comment: `why isnt working` what is the input? What does it mean "isn't working"? It should "is working" - but not the way _you_ expect. How do you expect it to work, or, what should the end goal be? || It's odd to use `g`lobal flag if you are matching `^` from the start. And use either `-E` or `-r`, they do the same.